# OpenRemoteBaseKey Values not returned

Tags: c#, powershell, registry

I am trying to use OpenRemoteBaseKey to query remote registry. This is the command I am executing against a few remote servers -

```
$Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('CurrentUser', $computername) 
$RegKey= $Reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings") 
$Proxy = $RegKey.GetValue("ProxyServer")
```

The problem is that I am getting results from some, but not getting the value from some other servers.

All servers are same OS, so no 32/64 bit issues. I have `WinRM` running, `Remote Registry` service is running and `Enable-PSRemoting` is also done on all remote servers. Also added Trusted Hosts on both sides, including on 'failing' remote systems. In addition to this, the account I am running the script 'as', is an Admin on both the working remote servers and failing remote servers.

P.S. Its only the above registry key that it doesn't return the value. If I run it to get say `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\` - `PathName` - even the failing servers successfully returns THIS value.

Any ideas what else I am missing?

Comment: Have you signed into the failing servers before, so that value is created under in HKCU your user profile?

Comment: I'm not sure that your registry hive is loaded on a remote server when you access it that way. Maybe you should do a `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' ProxyServer -ea 4} -ComputerName $computername` and see if that gets you the value.

Comment: BenH: I have logged in with the ID on one server incidentally, but it still doesn't pull the value (although would defeat the purpose if i had to do it on all).

Comment: TheMadTechnician: I tried the Invoke-Command but it gives the following: Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process th
e request. Default authentication may be used with an IP address under the following conditions: the transport is HTTPS
 or the destination is in the TrustedHosts list, and explicit credentials are provided. Use winrm.cmd to configure Trus
tedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.